# How can i add custom fields to ModelSerializer?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

i have a PurchaseDetail model like

```
class PurchaseDetail(NowTimestampAndUserModel):
    
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseMaster, default=False, related_name="purchase_details", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, default=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, default=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    sale_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    qty = models.FloatField(help_text="Purchase quantity")  
    ref_purchase_order_detail = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ref_purchase_detail = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

and i have "Item" model and "item_category" models as
ITEM

```
class ItemCategory(NowTimestampAndUserModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text="Category name should be max. of 50 characters")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, help_text="Province name should be max. of 10 characters")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

ITEM_CATEGORY

```
class ItemCategoryHist(NowTimestampAndUserModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Category name should be max. of 50 characters")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Province name should be max. of 10 characters")
  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i want to make serializer class as

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_name = Field(source='get_item_name')
   
    
    class Meta: 
        model = PurchaseDetail
        # some fields of PurchaseDetail 
        fields = ['id', 'item_name ', 'item_category']

    def get_item_name(self, obj):
        item_id = obj.item
        item_obj = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        name = item_obj.name
        return name
```

I want to serialize item name field only with Purchase Detai. How ca i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are Serializer Method Fields: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

The field "item_name" can be a SerializerMethodField, allowing you to have custom code to generate the value for that field.

Comment: Thank you. Got the solution through..... item_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='item.name')